What is the next step to troubleshoot Rails app not responding (Nginx and Passenger seem to be working)?
My Rails app is now deployed (using Capistrano) but doesn't seem to be receiving requests. If I try to connect from Safari it eventually times out, if I try to connect from Chromium I get "The site can't be reached, ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".
I can see the requests being logged by Passenger/Nginx in /var/log/nginx/access.log but even with Rails logging turned up to :debug, I'm not seeing any requests in log/production.log, only a couple of debug messages about ActiveRecord::InternalMetadata Load and ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load.
Restarting the app with passenger-config restart-app /home/deploy/myapp/current seems to work and the only thing that shows up in /var/log/nginx/error.log is:
[ N 2024-09-14 01:23:04.4806 59187/Td age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1147 ]: Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 80053, application /home/deploy/myapp/current (production)

The passenger processes are running and are pointed at my app:
> sudo /usr/sbin/passenger-memory-stats
Version: 6.0.23
Date   : 2024-09-14 01:52:13 +0000
------------- Apache processes -------------
*** WARNING: The Apache executable cannot be found.
Please set the APXS2 environment variable to your 'apxs2' executable's filename, or set the HTTPD environment variable to your 'httpd' or 'apache2' executable's filename.


---------- Nginx processes -----------
PID    PPID   VMSize    Private  Name
--------------------------------------
59205  1      197.1 MB  0.6 MB   nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
59206  59205  197.6 MB  0.8 MB   nginx: worker process
59208  59205  197.6 MB  0.8 MB   nginx: worker process
### Processes: 3
### Total private dirty RSS: 2.18 MB


----- Passenger processes ------
PID    VMSize     Private  Name
--------------------------------
59183  361.1 MB   2.8 MB   Passenger watchdog
59187  1045.2 MB  6.6 MB   Passenger core
80223  739.9 MB   78.4 MB  Passenger RubyApp: /home/deploy/myapp/current (production)
### Processes: 3
### Total private dirty RSS: 87.81 MB

DNS and HTTP both seem to be working because I can see all public pages (e.g. myapp.example.com/500.html), just not the ones being handed off to Passenger/Rack/Ruby/Rails.
My Rails app works in development. In production it seems to be working. That is, it can tell me the correct routes...:
> RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails routes
            Prefix  Verb  URI Pattern      Controller#Action
rails_health_check  GET   /up(.:format)    rails/health#show
              home  GET   /home(.:format)  pages#home
              root  GET   /                pages#coming_soon

...and I can start the server on a high level port:
UPDATE: previously this command was launching WEBrick instead of Passenger 
 RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails server
=> Booting Passenger application server
=> Rails 7.2.1 application starting in production http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
=============== Phusion Passenger(R) Standalone web server started ===============
PID file: /home/deploy/myapp/current/tmp/pids/passenger.3000.pid
Log file: /home/deploy/myapp/current/log/passenger.3000.log
Environment: production
Accessible via: http://0.0.0.0:3000/

I added Rack logging to my Rails app:
#config.ru
require_relative "config/environment"

logger = Logger.new("log/rack.log")
use Rack::CommonLogger, logger

run Rails.application
Rails.application.load_server

When I restart Passenger, the "rack.log" file gets created but no requests are being logged there.
As I understand it the flow is Client Browser → Nginx → Passenger → Rack → Rails. If I'm right, it seems like the problem is between Passenger and Rack?
Passenger knows about the correct Ruby (through rbenv):
> passenger-config about ruby-command
passenger-config was invoked through the following Ruby interpreter:
  Command: /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/3.3.4/bin/ruby
  Version: ruby 3.3.4 (2024-07-09 revision be1089c8ec) [x86_64-linux]
  To use in Apache: PassengerRuby /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/3.3.4/bin/ruby
  To use in Nginx : passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/3.3.4/bin/ruby
  To use with Standalone: /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/3.3.4/bin/ruby /usr/bin/passenger start

The following Ruby interpreter was found first in $PATH:
  Command: /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/3.3.4/bin/ruby
  Version: ruby 3.3.4 (2024-07-09 revision be1089c8ec) [x86_64-linux]
  To use in Apache: PassengerRuby /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/3.3.4/bin/ruby
  To use in Nginx : passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/3.3.4/bin/ruby
  To use with Standalone: /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/3.3.4/bin/ruby /usr/bin/passenger start

How can I verify that Passenger is successfully talking to my Ruby/Rack app? Is there something else I'm missing?
(My question is not "how do I fix it?", but "what else do I need to learn next to be able to figure it out and fix it myself?")

Vital stats in case they're relevant to the learning/troubleshooting process:

Ubuntu 24.04.01 LTS
rbenv 1.3.0-4-gc335ab8
Ruby 3.3.4
Rails 7.2.1
Nginx 1.24.0
Passenger 6.0.23


you need to understand why Passenger is not finding your rails app... it must be a configuration issue. In Passenger/Nginx configuration, all the Passenger configuration is done within the Nginx config files

Thanks for the pointer! The output of passenger-memory-stats suggests to me it knows where the app is... The third Passenger process listed is Passenger RubyApp: /home/deploy/myapp/current (production). I tried to find examples online of what the RubyApp line should look like... https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/1824 has /public appended to the end. My nginx.conf has root /home/deploy/myapp/current/public;

You can use passenger-config --nginx-bin to see your path to the Nginx binary if Passenger is properly set up to work with Nginx.
